# Bézout's identity on a polynome sequence

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

I'm stuck on an exercise which is split in 3 questions :

> **1)** Prove that : 
>   $$\exists (U_n, V_n) \in \mathbb{R}[X]^2 \text{ s.t. } (1-X)^{n+1}U_n+X^{n+1}V_n=1$$
>   **2)** Let $(R_n, S_n)\in\mathbb{R}[X]^2$ the remainders of the *ED* of respectively $U_n$ by $X^{n+1}$ and $V_n$ by $(1-X)^{n+1}$. Prove that :
>   $$(1-X)^{n+1}R_n+X^{n+1}S_n=1$$
>   **3)** Prove then that :
>   $$\exists !(A_n,B_n)\in\mathbb{R}[X]^2, d°(A_n) \leq n \text{ and }d°(B_n)\leq n, \text{ s.t. } (1-X)^{n+1}A_n+X^{n+1}B_n=1$$

So for **1)**, I've been saying :

As $1$ is a root of multiplicity $n+1$ of $(1-X)^{n+1}$ and $d°((1-X)^{n+1})=n+1$, whereas $0$ is a root of multiplicity $n+1$ of $X^{n+1}$ and $d°(X^{n+1})=n+1$, $(1-X)^{n+1}$ and $X^{n+1}$ share no complex roots, which means :
$$X^{n+1} \wedge (1-X)^{n+1} = 1$$
Hence, using *Bézout's identity* :
$$\exists (U_n, V_n) \in \mathbb{R}[X]^2 \text{ s.t. } (1-X)^{n+1}U_n+X^{n+1}V_n=1$$

For the second question, I've been trying to write down the definition of $R_n$ and $S_n$ :
$$U_n = P_nX^{n+1}+R_n$$
$$V_n = Q_n(1-X)^{n+1}+S_n$$

And then trying multiples things but it leaded me nowhere.

Could you give me some hints ? (No complete proof please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** It is a proof devoid of content to invoke Bezout's to solve an exercise that is asking to prove Bezout's. I would instead use Euclid's algorithm to show how to construct some $U_n,V_n$.

> Alternatively we can do this trick. Observe that $$\frac{U_n(X)}{X^{n+1}}+\frac{V_n(X)}{(1-X)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{X^{n+1}(1-X)^{n+1}}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(1)}$$
>
> If we write $$U_n(X)=a_0+a_1X+...a_nX^n$$ and $$V_n(X)=b_0-b_1(X-1)+...+(-1)^nb_n(X-1)^n$$
>
> We see that (1) is the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{X^n(1-X)^n}$. So we can find their coefficients directly. Since
> $$U_n(X)+\frac{X^{n+1}V_n(X)}{(1-X)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{(1-X)^{n+1}}$$ then $U_n(X)$ is the first $n+1$ terms of the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-X)^{n+1}}$. But we know the Taylor expansion from the binomial theorem
> $$\frac{1}{(1-X)^{n+1}}=(1-X)^{-(n+1)}\\=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\binom{-(n+1)}{k}X^k$$
> So, $$\begin{align}a_k&=(-1)^k\binom{-(n+1)}{k}\\&=(-1)^k\frac{(-n-1)(-n-1-1)(-n-1-2)...(-n-1-(k-1))}{k!}\\&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k)}{k!}\end{align}$$
> Similarly one can find $b_k$.

**2** Assume you already have some equation $$(1-X)^{n+1}U_n+X^{n+1}V_n=1$$ and $U_n=X^nP+R$ with $d(R)\leq n$. Then $$(1-X)^{n+1}R+X^{n+1}[V_n+X^{n+1}P]=1$$

The claim is that we are done. You just need to count the degree of $(1-X)^{n+1}R$, notice that this must cancel with $X^{n+1}[V+X^{n+1}P]$, and deduce that $d[V+(1-X)^{n+1}P]\leq n$. Therefore, $V+(1-X)^{n+1}P$ is already the remainder of $V$ after division by $(1-X)^{n+1}$.

**3** Follows from **2**.

Comment: Actually, the exercise is not about proving Bézout's (else, indeed, that would be quite easy -even if it is maybe already ? -), but rather about proving uniqueness of such polynomials of degree at most $n$. So basically, it means that $d°(P_n) = -\infty$, right ?

Comment: @servabat No, why? Not necessarily. If the $U$ and $V$ that you start with do not satisfy $d(U)\leq n$ then $P$ is not necessarily $0$. The important thing is to notice that once you divide $U$ by $X^{n+1}$ and pass $(1-X)^{n+1}P$ to the other term, the degree of the other term gets reduced automatically.

Comment: @servabat The whole problem guides you through the steps of proving Bezout's theorem (for those polynomials). The step in **2** being the last step. That is another reason for not just invoking Bezout's as a black box before making sure we know well the proof of Bezout's.

Comment: Then I probably didn't understood **2)** then. If we write the equality $(1-X)^{n+1}R_n + X^{n+1}(V_n+(1-X)^{n+1}P_n$, we then have on the LHS $d°((1-X)^{n+1}R_n) \leq 2n+1$ and $d°(X^{n+1}(V_n+(1-X)^{n+1}P_n)) \leq n + 1 + max(d°(Vn), d°((1-X)^{n+1}P_n)$. But $d°((1-X)^{n+1}P_n) = n+1+d°(P_n)$ so as on the RHS $d°(1) = 0$, we then have $c((1-X)^{n+1}R_n) = -c(X^{n+1}(V_n+(1-X)^{n+1}P_n)$ and the 2 degrees of the sum are also equal, so $d°(P_n)$ must be zero, no ?

Comment: @servabat No, I don't know what the degree of $P$ can be. It depends on the initial $U$ and $V$ we start with. Notice that if $U,V$ satisfy the equation, then for any polynomial $H$,  $\widetilde{U}:=U+X^{n+1}H$ and $\widetilde{V}:=V-(1-X)^{n+1}H$ also satisfy the equation. Therefore the degree of $P$ could be as large as you want. The important thing is that $d(V+(1-X)^{n+1}P)\leq n$. That's all.

Comment: The inequality $d(V+(1-X)^{n+1}P)\leq n$ means that we don't need to Euclid-divide $V$ by $(1-X)^{n+1}$, because it is already divided: $V=(-P)\cdot(1-X)^{n+1}+(V+(1-X)^{n+1}P)=(1-X)^{n+1}Q+S$.

Comment: Those are the two key ideas in proving Bezout's theorem. (1) The use of Euclid's algorithm to find one solution. (2) The trick of dividing one factor to reduce the degree, plus the observation that the other factor gets reduced automatically.

Comment: But if $d°(P_n) \neq -\infty$, then $d°((1-X)^{n+1}P_n \geq n+1)$, and then it cannot "disappear" with the first term so that the degree is $0$.

Comment: @servabat Think about it for a while. Everything that you need is already written in the comments above. $V$ can also have degree $\geq n+1$ and cancel the terms of $(1-X)^{n+1}P$.